# Building a dataframe in an efficient way from dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have large set of data that I have process and generated a dictionary. Now I want to create a dataframe from this dictionary. Vales of the dictionary are list of tuples. From those values I need to find out the unique values to build the columns of the dataframe:

```
d = {'0001': [('skiing',0.789),('snow',0.65),('winter',0.56)],'0002': [('drama', 0.89),('comedy', 0.678),('action',-0.42) ('winter',-0.12),('kids',0.12)],'0003': [('action', 0.89),('funny', 0.58),('sports',0.12)],'0004': [('dark', 0.89),('Mystery', 0.678),('crime',0.12), ('adult',-0.423)],'0005': [('cartoon', -0.89),('comedy', 0.678),('action',0.12)],'0006': [('drama', -0.49),('funny', 0.378),('Suspense',0.12), ('Thriller',0.78)],'0007': [('dark', 0.79),('Mystery', 0.88),('crime',0.32), ('adult',-0.423)]}
```

(size of the dictionary close to 800,000 records)

I iterate over the dictionary to find out the unique headers:

```
col_headers = []
entities = []
for key, scores in d.iteritems():
    entities.append(key)
    d[key] = dict(scores)
    col_headers.extend(d[key].keys())
col_headers = list(set(col_headers))
```

I believe this take long time to process. Using `dict` might also be an issue since its much slower. Further more when I construct the data frame raw by raw it further slows down the process:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_headers, index=entities)
for k in d:
    df.loc[k] = pd.Series(d[k])
df.fillna(0.0, axis=1)
```

How can I speed up this process to reduce to the process time?

Comment: Does `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').fillna(0)` give you the outcome you want?

Comment: No, it will not generate column headers and populate the values under each column

Comment: Oops - my problem was that I used `d` in that construction *after* it had been changed by the code in the question (so I thought `d` already contained dicts (not lists of tuples)) :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[@ajcr almost gets it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29086273/building-a-dataframe-in-an-efficient-way-from-dictionary#comment46405817_29086273)

But you probably also need to unwrap the internal key-value pairs into a dictionary along the way.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({ k: dict(v) for k,v in d.items() },  
                            orient="index").fillna(0)
```

Then optionally, if you want to homogenize the style of column titles:

```
df.columns = [c.lower() for c in df.columns]
```

[image]

If you wanted to go entirely crazy, you could then sort the columns:

```
df = df.sort(axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. Can you explain `df.columns = [c.lower() for c in df.columns]` a bit because I looked at the df prior to doing that operation and it looked the same.

Comment: You have a few column names in the original data that have capitalized keys (e.g. Mystery, Suspense, and Thriller). But most of the column names are lower case (e.g. drama, action, and cartoon). IMO, the columns look better all lower-case (`.lower()`), or all capitalized (`.capitalize()`). So that second statement is just giving them all the same "look."

Comment: It is arguably better to map the input data dictionaries to have all lower-case keys before they are pulled into the `DataFrame`. This is especially true if the original data had inconsistently capitalized keys (e.g. some "Mystery" and some "mystery"). I know no magically simple way to do that. The easiest is probably subclassing `dict` along the lines of [PEP 455](https://github.com/alexprengere/transformdict.git). But this data set doesn't require that much extra.

Comment: @Jonathan_Eunice if I have a dictionary where its keys are data frames indexes can I how do I filter such that data frame only contain the keys of the dictionary.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis Good question. Post that as separate question and I'll take a shot at answering. Please provide a real example, though, as there are several possible interpretations.

Comment: @Jonathan_Eunice  Just did but I simplified it by using a list, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134458/pandas-data-frame-filter-by-list-values-most-efficient