# Pandas data frame filter by list values - most efficient

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following pandas data frame that I have build:

```
      dark  Mystery  adult  crime  action  comedy  cartoon  winter  snow  skiing
0001  0.00    0.000  0.000   0.00    0.00   0.000     0.00    0.56  0.65   0.789
0004  0.89    0.678 -0.423   0.12    0.00   0.000     0.00    0.00  0.00   0.000
0005  0.00    0.000  0.000   0.00    0.12   0.678    -0.89    0.00  0.00   0.000
```

I also have a list that has some of the row index values of the data frame. After filtering I want to have my new data frame with indexes matching the values in the list.

```
l = [001,005]
```

This is large data frame I am trying to figure out without iterating via loop.

```
[df.index[idx] for idx in l]
```

This is wrong but I feel I am close to the answer or may be not.

Result should be:

```
      dark  Mystery  adult  crime  action  comedy  cartoon  winter  snow  skiing
0001  0.00    0.000  0.000   0.00    0.00   0.000     0.00    0.56  0.65   0.789
0005  0.00    0.000  0.000   0.00    0.12   0.678    -0.89    0.00  0.00   0.000
```

Comment: df.ix[l] will return a view of the underlying data, where l is your list.  Note that idx may be a more readable name than l.

Answer (score 3):

How about using [`.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing):

```
df.loc[l]
```

Note, in your actual example, your indices are probably strings rather than integers.  When you declare `l = [0001, 0005]` it's going to be evaluated as `[1,5]`.  So you might want to use `l = ["0001", "0005"]` or use string formatting to convert the integers (as Jonathan Eunice shows in his answer).

As an aside, [you should also avoid using lowercase `l` as a variable name](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid), since it looks similar to `1` in many monospace typefaces.

Comment: values in my list are in following format -> `u'0001'`

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis, I see.  Your question seemed to indicate differently.  Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If your DataFrame is in `df`:

```
newdf = df[df.index.isin(l)]
```

Of course, you have to be careful here. None of your items in l are truly in the index. `l = [001,005]` is the same as `l = [1,5]`, whereas your index is really strings a la `['0001', '0002', ...]`. Given that, you may want to "upgrade" your selection list `l` to be parallel to your index first:

```
l = ["{:04d}".format(i) for i in l ]
newdf = df[df.index.isin(l)]
```

Comment: values in my list are in following format -> `u'0001'` based on that I don't think the format is required thats by guess.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis If your values are in that format, I agree. But in your question, you state `l = [001,005]` which would make them integers. Even if you assume they're strings, they have the wrong number of leading zeros. So, if the selection list is already more on-target than the question suggests, great! If not, you will need to homogenize the selection list with the DataFrame index.